# C#.net webbrowser control and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a Problem with the Webbrowser control in my c# code. 
First the Website, I'll show with the control, seems to work well.
But after closing and reopen my Form with the web browser-Control SEVEN times,
the Website throws a JavaScript SecurityError.  The specific js code line is opening a web socket.
After that, it only helps to restart the application to get the Website work again.

I already indicated, that it only exists on Windows 10. On Windows 7/8 the application works fine.

I already tried the  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION-reg-key. But it didn't help.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: And you don't have this behavior on this site in any other browser? Other websites work normally in your application? What is the code you use to instantiate the webbrowser control and to open the website?

Comment: other Websites work fine. Also when I work with the Internet Explorer, it works fine (all Websites including the problematic one). I only have the problem with this one Website in the webbrowser-control. code is: webBrowser1.Navigate("<localip:adress>"). I didn't change anything in the Webbrowser control. I only use the navigate-Method

Comment: Ok, then it seems more like a problem with the website. Perhaps there is a cookie set, that doesn't get reset as expected? Did you trace what exactly (in javascript) triggers the error?

Comment: as I can retrace, it happens in this js-Funktion: function ws(uri, protocols, opts) {
  var instance;
  if (protocols) {
    instance = new WebSocket(uri, protocols);
  } else {
    instance = new WebSocket(uri);
  }
  return instance;
} . The error happens in the else-case. But the strange thing is, that error happens only in the Webbrowser control. With the Internet Explorer on the same machine is not reproducible

Comment: Actually I changed to the gecko-Webbrowser  plugin. With this my application works fine (including the problematic Website)